# Vertically and horizontally aligning a div containing h1 tag and a p tag

Tags: html, css, sass, alignment

I'm trying to horizontally and vertically align my banner text like so:

[image: design]

I have been searching around for the best way possible and have found it very difficult. It could be something really easy that i've missed and wasted a few hours on but I guess that's learning!

This is my html

```
<header class="fullscreen" style="background-image: url('images/bg.png');">
        <div class="logo-wrapper text-center">
            <img id="logo" src="" alt="The South-West Skateboarding (SWSB) logo." />
        </div>
        <nav id="primary" class="text-center">
            <a href="/">HOME</a> |
            <a href="/about">ABOUT</a> |
            <a href="/team">TEAM</a> |
            <a href="/gallery">GALLERY</a> |
            <a href="/forum">FORUM</a> |
            <a href="/login">LOGIN</a>
        </nav>
        <div id="banner" >
            <h1>SOUTH-WEST SKATEBOARDING</h1>
            <p>EST. 2016</p>
        </div>
    </header>
```

And css (sorry it's in sass, shouldnt make much of a difference)

```
header {

    padding: 50px 0 50px 0;
    height: 100%;

    .logo-wrapper {
        margin: 0 auto;
        width: 100%;

        img#logo {
                width: 140px;
                height: 85px;
        }
    }


    nav#primary {
        margin-top: 25px;

        a {
            color: $nav-link-color;
            font-weight: 100;
            letter-spacing: 2.15px;
            text-decoration: none;
            text-transform: uppercase;
        }
    }

    #banner {
        h1 {
            margin-bottom: 0;
        }

        p {
            margin: 0;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/c6s5qrqm/)

```
#banner {
    width: 100%;
    height: 400px;
    background-color: yellow;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center
}
```

Comment: @HarveyEL if your problem is solved please accept the answer, or let me know the issue.

Comment: Hi mate, thank you for your reply. It centers it but unfortunately the established text is inline with the h1 element.

EDIT: I saw what you did with the HTML and it works fine, thank you! Is there any better way of doing this though?

Comment: you can see all the possibilities here https://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/center.en.html

Comment: @HarveyEL Please accept the answer if your problem is solved and you are satisfied with the answer, so people can help others, instead of again posting answers here.

Comment: @HarveyEL his answer is right, accept it as the right one please, a better way depends on your browser support. Best approach i think is using flexbox - Check this guide https://css-tricks.com/centering-css-complete-guide/